# Which is the address that runs requestRandomWords if I'm using Chainlink automation?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

Helloo aall!! I'm having some troubles when using time-based automation with request random numbers. What I'm trying to do is to request random numbers every 10 mins. I'm using the subscription mode in my VRFConsumerBaseV2 contract and I think the problem is that I don't know what is ConfirmedOwner... which is the address I should set there if requestRandomWords is being run by an automation oracle? The registry address, the upkeep address, ...? This is the constructor of my VRFConsumerBaseV2 contract:

```
constructor(address _consumer, uint64 _subscriptionId, address _oracle)
        VRFConsumerBaseV2(_consumer)
        ConfirmedOwner(_oracle)
    {
        COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(
            _consumer
        );
        s_subscriptionId = _subscriptionId;
    }
```

And well this is the requestRandomWords, with the onlyOwner that is set with the ConfirmedOwner in the constructor, no?:

```
function requestRandomWords(uint32 _numWords) public onlyOwner returns (uint256) {
        // Will revert if subscription is not set and funded.
        requestId = COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
            keyHash,
            s_subscriptionId,
            requestConfirmations,
            callbackGasLimit,
            _numWords
        );
        emit RequestSent(requestId, _numWords);
        return requestId;
    }
```

Thank yooouuu so muuch!!!

Answer (score 1):

It's the upkeep address that you can see in the console of Chainlink oracles.

Answer (score 1):

A few of the FAQ from the [Chainlink Docs](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/faqs/) should help clear this up.

### Which contract will call my `performUpkeep` function on-chain?

The [Automation Registry](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/supported-networks/) will call the `performUpkeep` function on-chain.

### Will the address of the Automation Registry always stay the same?

No. As we add new functionality we have to upgrade our contract and deploy a new Automation Registry. We will work with all our users to ensure Upkeeps are migrated without causing business interruptions.

### Can I require that `performUpkeep` is only callable by the Automation Registry?

Our preferred and recommended route before locking access to `performUpkeep` is [revalidation](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/compatible-contracts/#revalidate-performupkeep). We understand you might want to add a require statement, but then recommend that you make the Automation Registry address configurable otherwise you will need to deploy a new contract when the Registry address changes. If you add a `require` statement to `performUpkeep` you will have to update the Registry Address in your contract when the Registry Address changes. We also recommend that the owner can always call `performUpkeep`.